# number guess application using visual c++ and cgi

Tags: visual-c++, cookies, cgi

I am developing cgi number guess  application using visual c++. The number is sent from form to be guessed. It is compared with random number stored in cookie. Also number of guesses are managed for each number to be guessed. If number to be guessed matches with the cookie number i have to reinitialize counter. For that i have to create new cookie "ReintializeguessCookie" but it is not creating in the following fragment.

```
if(Guesscounter==0){

        cout << "Set-Cookie: ReintializeguessCookie=" <<0<< endl;   


    }
```

"Set-Cookie: ReintializeguessCookie=0"  line is printing in html form instead of creating cookie. Please let me know how to solve it. Thanks

Here is a complete code:

```
#include "parse.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    char* varptr;   
    size_t size;
    int requestType;
    int count = 0;

    int num=0 ;
    int check=1;
    _dupenv_s(&varptr, &size, "HTTP_COOKIE");
    if(varptr != 0)
    {   

        Parse list( varptr );

        char *sptr = list.get_item( "ReqCount" );
        char *sptr2 = list.get_item( "guessCookie" );
        char *sptr3 = list.get_item( "ReintializeguessCookie" );

        if (sptr != NULL)
        {

            sscanf_s(sptr, "%d", &count);

            delete [] sptr;
        }

        if (sptr2 != NULL)
        {
            sscanf_s(sptr2, "%d", &num);

            delete [] sptr2;
        }
        if (sptr3 != NULL)
        {
            sscanf_s(sptr3, "%d", &check);
            delete [] sptr3;

        }
        count++;
        srand(time(0));
    num=rand()% (11 - 1) +1;
        free(varptr);

        if(check==0){
            count=0;
        }

    }

    cout << "Set-Cookie: ReqCount=" << count << endl;
    cout << "Set-Cookie: guessCookie=" <<num  << endl;


    cout << "Content-type: text/html" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    // Here is the beginning of the HTML page
    cout << "<html>" << endl
         << "<body>" << endl
         << "<title> Environment Variables </title>" << endl
         << "<p>" << endl;

    _dupenv_s(&varptr, &size, "REQUEST_METHOD");
    if(varptr != 0)
    {
        cout << "REQUEST_METHOD = " << varptr << "<br>" << endl;
        // Remember which request type it is so we know how to get the query string
        if (varptr[0] == 'g' || varptr[0] == 'G')
            requestType = 0;    // HTTP GET request - query string in an environment variable
        else
            requestType = 1;    // HTTP POST request - query string in the body
        free(varptr);
    }
    if (requestType == 0)
    {
        // For HTTP GET requests, get the query string from the environment
        _dupenv_s(&varptr, &size, "QUERY_STRING");
    }
    else
    {

        int nContentLength;
        _dupenv_s(&varptr, &size, "CONTENT_LENGTH");

        sscanf_s(varptr, "%d", &nContentLength);
        free(varptr);
        // Now, allocate memory for the HTTP request body
        varptr = (char *)malloc(nContentLength+1);
        // Set the allocated memory to 0
        memset(varptr, 0, nContentLength+1);

        fread(varptr,1,nContentLength,stdin);
    }
    int Guesscounter=1;
    if(varptr != 0)
    {   

        char *sptr; // Pointer to the string containing a value returned by get_item
        int Guessnumber;  // A float variable for use with sscanf_s

        Parse list( varptr ); // Create the Parse object with the query string!


        sptr = list.get_item( "guess" );
        if(sptr != NULL)
        {
            // The client entered a Fahrenheit temp, so let's convert it to celcius!
            cout << "guess = " << sptr << "<br>" << endl;
            // Get the value of the fahrenheit input into the far variable
            sscanf_s(sptr, "%d", &Guessnumber); 
            // Now output the celcius equivalent to the client.
            //cout << "The celcius value is " << 5.0/9.0 * (far - 32) << "<br>" << endl;
            if(Guessnumber<num){
            cout << "The guess is low" << "<br>" << endl;
            }
                if(Guessnumber>num){
            cout << "The guess is high" << "<br>" << endl;
            }
                if(Guessnumber==num){
                    Guesscounter=0;
            cout << "The guess is exact" << "<br>" << endl;



            }
                    delete [] sptr;

    }
        // Free up the query string memory
        free(varptr);

    }


    cout << "<br>The number of guesses = " << count << endl;

        cout << "<br>Compared Guess is  = " << num << endl;

    // Complete our HTML document!
    cout << "</p>" << "</body>" << endl << "</html>" << endl;
    if(Guesscounter==0){

        cout << "Set-Cookie: ReintializeguessCookie=" <<0<< endl;   


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should emit your reinitializeCookie in the header (same place where you set other cookies). Now you are emitting it as part of the HTML.

Comment: but how can i set counter to 0?

Comment: Do all your calculations before emitting the page body?